# Java Nashorn longBitsToDouble

Tags: javascript, java

I'm running a moderately basic script through nashorn. I evaluate the script and return a handler object that was built inside the script to java. The scripts are done executing but can handle future input from java.

I'm having extremely high cpu usage. I had a lot of trouble profiling the application to figure out the source of my cpu issues. From what I can tell
Double.longBitsToDouble is causing 30% of my high cpu load. I dont know what is calling that method from my nashorn code but it would be nice to avoid it if possible.

Other noteworthy actions in my script would be that I am running a lot of Math.pow operations.

Any tips on how to get rid of this longBitsToDouble problem?

Comment: Can you post the relevant JavaScript? Of note, the JS [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Number) type is floating-point.

Comment: The code is a proprietary algorithm that ive been working on. My hunch is that java is assuming one of my variables in the script are a long? I use doubles for all of my location data in the formula so im thinking that may be part of it.  In terms of what you said, it seems like javascript prefers floating point over doubles. do you think that changing my location data over from double to floats would improve the performance?

Comment: It seems that the answer to this is both simple and complicated. After running my script and really watching the cpu the whole time I noticed that the usage plummets from a stable 30% to 0-3% based on spikes.

It looks like nashorn or my jvm needed some time to warm up? I was really worried about just accepting the idea that warming up is the solution so i increased my normal iterations of 64 to 1000 and the cpu was still at less than 3%. In my eyes this is problem solved until I see otherwise.

This does raise a few questions for me, is there any way to warm this thing up beforehand?